# Set expandAll/showAllNodes nodes by default on the Task Store Ext Gantt scheduler

Tags: extjs

I am using a Gantt + scheduler just like one here http://www.bryntum.com/examples/gantt-latest/examples/advanced/advanced.html but on a version as follows:
ext-4.2.2.1144 and gantt-2.2.22. I am facing a strange issue where the task list on the left panel is not completely visible and gets truncated from the middle.
But when the arrow on the left side of the root task is used for collapsing/expanding the list several times,it adds up the missing list each time.
There is only one root tasks having child tasks and it s child records are also having further child records.

I used **showAllNodes()** on the Task Store in the console and it started showing data,it turned out that it has been automatically filtering data.

Is there any method to turn this off by default?Or set a expandAll/showAllnodes by default for the tree store?

Please suggest.

[image: In the screenshot you can see list upto "Genra Trade.." but is actually very long and show up in steps when collapse/expand is done.]

Thanks.

Comment: Can you reproduce it on fiddle?

Comment: @Lolo I found out that it is automatically filtering the data on initial load.Filtering does not persist when collapse/expand is used and hence it starts showing up records after that.I used function showAllNodes() on the Task Store in console and it shows up the data then.Any idea how it can be set to show all the data by default?
thanks